# Word2Vec + CNN Overfitting

Tags: python, keras, nlp, conv-neural-network, word2vec

Currently I'am training my Word2Vec + CNN for Twitter sentiment analysis about COVID-19 vaccine domain. I used the pre-trained GoogleNewsVectorNegative300 word embedding. The problem is why I heavily overfit on training proses. The reason I used the pre-trained GoogleNewsVectorNegative300 because the performance much worse when I trained my own Word2Vec using own dataset. Here several processes that I have done before fitting the model:

Text Pre processing:

1. Lower casing
2. Remove hashtag, mentions, URLs, numbers, change words to numbers, non-ASCII characters, retweets "RT"
3. Expand contractions
4. Replace negations with antonyms
5. Remove puncutations
6. Remove stopwords
7. Lemmatization

I split my dataset into 90:10 for train:test as follows:

```
def split_data(X, y):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, 
                                                        y,
                                                        train_size=0.9, 
                                                        test_size=0.1, 
                                                        stratify=y,
                                                        random_state=0)
    return X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test
```

The split data resulting in training has 2060 samples with 708 positive sentiment class, 837 negative sentiment class, and 515 sentiment neutral class
Training:
[image]
Testing:
[image]

Then, I implemented the text augmentation that is EDA (Easy Data Augmentation) on all the training data as follows:

```
class TextAugmentation:
    def __init__(self):
        self.augmenter = EDA()

    def replace_synonym(self, text):
        augmented_text_portion = int(len(text)*0.1) 
        synonym_replaced = self.augmenter.synonym_replacement(text, n=augmented_text_portion)
        return synonym_replaced

    def random_insert(self, text):
        augmented_text_portion = int(len(text)*0.1) 
        random_inserted = self.augmenter.random_insertion(text, n=augmented_text_portion)
        return random_inserted

    def random_swap(self, text):
        augmented_text_portion = int(len(text)*0.1)
        random_swaped = self.augmenter.random_swap(text, n=augmented_text_portion)
        return random_swaped

    def random_delete(self, text):
        random_deleted = self.augmenter.random_deletion(text, p=0.5)
        return random_deleted

text_augmentation = TextAugmentation()
```

The data augmentation resulting in training has 10300 samples with 3540 positive sentiment class, 4185 negative sentiment class, and 2575 sentiment neutral class

Then, I tokenized the sequence as follows:

```
# Tokenize the sequence
pfizer_tokenizer = Tokenizer(oov_token='OOV')
pfizer_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df_pfizer_train['text'].values)

X_pfizer_train_tokenized = pfizer_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df_pfizer_train['text'].values)
X_pfizer_test_tokenized = pfizer_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df_pfizer_test['text'].values)

# Pad the sequence
X_pfizer_train_padded = pad_sequences(X_pfizer_train_tokenized, maxlen=100)
X_pfizer_test_padded = pad_sequences(X_pfizer_test_tokenized, maxlen=100)

pfizer_max_length = 100
pfizer_num_words = len(pfizer_tokenizer.word_index) + 1

# Encode label
y_pfizer_train_encoded = df_pfizer_train['sentiment'].factorize()[0]
y_pfizer_test_encoded = df_pfizer_test['sentiment'].factorize()[0]

y_pfizer_train_category = to_categorical(y_pfizer_train_encoded)
y_pfizer_test_category = to_categorical(y_pfizer_test_encoded)
```

Resulting in 8869 unique words and 100 maximum sequence length

Finally, I fit the into my model using pre trained GoogleNewsVectorNegative300 word embedding and CNN, and I split my training data again with 10% for validation as follows:

```
# Build single CNN model
def build_cnn_model(embedding_matrix, max_sequence_length):
    # Input layer
    input_layer = Input(shape=(max_sequence_length,))

    # Word embedding layer
    embedding_layer = Embedding(input_dim=embedding_matrix.shape[0],
                                output_dim=embedding_matrix.shape[1],
                                weights=[embedding_matrix],
                                input_length=max_sequence_length,
                                trainable=True)(input_layer)

    # CNN model layer
    cnn_layer = Conv1D(filters=256,
                        kernel_size=2,
                        strides=1,
                        padding='valid',
                        activation='relu')(embedding_layer)
    cnn_layer = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(cnn_layer)
    cnn_layer = Dropout(rate=0.5)(cnn_layer)
    batch_norm_layer = BatchNormalization()(cnn_layer)

    
    cnn_layer = Conv1D(filters=256,
                        kernel_size=2,
                        strides=1,
                        padding='valid',
                        activation='relu')(batch_norm_layer)
    cnn_layer = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(cnn_layer)
    cnn_layer = Dropout(rate=0.5)(cnn_layer)
    batch_norm_layer = BatchNormalization()(cnn_layer)

    
    cnn_layer = Conv1D(filters=256,
                        kernel_size=2,
                        strides=1,
                        padding='valid',
                        activation='relu')(batch_norm_layer)
    cnn_layer = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(cnn_layer)
    cnn_layer = Dropout(rate=0.5)(cnn_layer)
    batch_norm_layer = BatchNormalization()(cnn_layer)


    flatten = Flatten()(batch_norm_layer)
    
    # Dense model layer
    dense_layer = Dense(units=10, activation='relu')(flatten)
    batch_norm_layer = BatchNormalization()(dense_layer)
    output_layer = Dense(units=3, activation='softmax')(batch_norm_layer)
  
    cnn_model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
  
    return cnn_model

    return lstm_model

sinovac_cnn_history = sinovac_cnn_model.fit(x=X_sinovac_train,
                                                  y=y_sinovac_train,
                                                  batch_size=128,
                                                  epochs=100,
                                                  validation_split=0.1,
                                                  verbose=1)
```

[image]

The training result:
[image]

I really need some suggestions or insights because I have been doing this without any performance progress to my model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's quite a complex problem. It sure looks like overfitting as you said yourself. Meaning the model can't generalize well from your training set to new data.

Intuitively, I would suggest for you to cycle hyperparameters (epochs, batch size, learning rate, dropout layers), if you didn't already, to seek a better combination. Also, I would suggest to use [cross-validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) to get a better idea of the performance of your classifier. This would also shuffle the training data and avoid that the model learns the data by heart.

Have you tried classifying the original data without the data augmentation? It's not a lot of data, but it could be enough to see if the performance on the test set is better than the final version, and thus see whether the data augmentation might be screwing something up in your data.

Did you try another embedding? I don't really think this is the problem, but in the search for the error I would probably switch it to see what happens.

Last but not least, do you know for a fact that this model structure can handle this task? Meaning did you find a working example somewhere? It sure sounds like it could do it, but there is the chance that the CNN model for example just doesn't generalize well over the embeddings. Have you considered using a model specified on text classification, like a Transformer or an LSTM?

Comment: 1. For tunning, I increased the dropout to 0.9 each of them and produced worst performance, so I stick with 0.5 rate dropout; for the epoch I increase the epoch the validation performance still no progress; I haven't tried the cross validation maybe you can give me the source or the reference

2. I have not tried the original data, I will try it

3. I haven't tried another embeddings, because I have limited resource on my hardware, I changed to the pre trained embedding as I mentioned before I tried to train own Word2Vec model with own data the result is much worse and overfit badly

Comment: 4. I used several works like research as my starting model, because they claimed has 90% accuracy on the model with simillar data length but they have not implemented data augmentation yet, for the other model I tried LSTM which is performed better, but I need to get good performance on the CNN as my requirement project

Comment: Here are the papers I used:  (https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3457206) (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9336549/) (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11042-019-07788-7) where I took the CNN architecture that they used

Comment: Okay, so then the approach should work in general. Another thought came to my mind: if you have a high variance in training and test samples, say
`The movie was pretty nice. - Train / Positive`
`We had a good time. - Train / Positive`
`Jolly piece of work. - Test / Positive`
Then of course the classifier will have a hard time recognizing the last one. Did you check that training and test samples are about similar in nature?
The cross-validation source is linked when you click on it, but here is the link again: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html

Comment: So any additional suggestions ? , then how to check the training and test sample for similar in nature ? I have to check every texts ? I have edited my question with additional training and test distribution on each label, you may have a look there

Comment: And one more, should I implement the Easy Data Augmentaiton on training data only ? So I need to split the full data into training, validation, and test set, then, augment the training data ? Because currently, I augmented both the training and validation data, I'am afraid that caused the model to confuse

Comment: I am not quite sure what the data augmentation actually does with your data. You can try augmenting only training, see what it does. To check similarity I meant looking at 20 to 30 samples to see whether training and test set are similar sentences -- but I think this should be the case usually.

Comment: For the data augmentation, you can refer to this paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.11196.pdf); btw I'll try your suggestions, thank you

Comment: Yeah, I took 20 samples and compare between the training and validation data, it seems most of the sentences is has no similar between them, so what should I do ?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't have any more suggestions beyond the ones I posted. One last advice I can give is to post your issue in the GitHub repository or a discussion forum of the architecture you are using, if there is one. E.g. for Transformers there is a whole community helping with these questions, maybe there is something similar for your model?